# How does WinSCP know what a symlink links to when showing directory listings?

Tags: sftp, putty, winscp

When you connect with WinSCP to a directory that contains a symlink it'll show you that it's a symlink by using a slightly different icon. eg. instead of just a folder it'll be a folder with an arrow or some such.

My question is...  how does WinSCP know that the symlink is a symlink to a folder?

When you SFTP into a directory the client sends a `SSH_FXP_READDIR` packet. The server responds with a `SSH_FXP_NAME` packet. In my testing it seems that the data in this packet corresponds to lstat - not stat. ie. if you AND the permissions attribute with `1111 0000 0000 0000` you get `1010 0000 0000 0000` (symlink) instead of `0100 0000 0000 0000` (directory).

My guess is that WinSCP then sends out a `SSH_FXP_STAT` for each of these symlinks but maybe it's doing `SSH_FXP_READLINK` instead. If the latter the server would respond with `SSH_FXP_NAME` - if the former the server would respond with `SSH_FXP_ATTRS` (which is pretty much an `SSH_FXP_NAME` for just one file instead of x files). But then again, maybe it's doing something else entirely.

Remembering that WinSCP uses PuTTY I tried to see which one it was doing by creating a session with PuTTY that had "Session logging" set to "SSH packets". I then tried to connect to that session with WinSCP but no putty.log file was created. I didn't see it in the directory where I had initially ran PuTTY to update the session nor did I see it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP`. So I have no idea where it is.

Any ideas?

Comment: To the person who voted to have this closed...  I'm not asking about how to use WinSCP. If I were I'd agree with you that this ought to be moved to Super User. But I'm not. I'm asking how WinSCP is implementing a particular feature. ie. what packets are being sent to and fro. Don't let my last paragraph about the logs distract you from what the question is ultimately asking - my including that paragraph was just an attempt to be thorough - to document what I've tried to do to figure it out.

Comment: I'd say that a correct way to ask would be *"How to tell what a symlink links to with SFTP protocol?"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinSCP sends both `SSH_FXP_STAT` and `SSH_FXP_READLINK`.

The `SSH_FXP_STAT` to find out, if the symlink points to a file or a directory.

The `SSH_FXP_READLINK` to find out link target.

---

See [WinSCP log](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/logging):

```
. 2015-07-20 11:00:15.837 Listing directory "...".
> 2015-07-20 11:00:15.837 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 53, Number: 11275
< 2015-07-20 11:00:15.894 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 13, Number: 11275
> 2015-07-20 11:00:15.894 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 13, Number: 11532
< 2015-07-20 11:00:15.950 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 431, Number: 11532
> 2015-07-20 11:00:15.950 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 13, Number: 11788
. 2015-07-20 11:00:15.950 Reading symlink "link".
> 2015-07-20 11:00:15.950 Type: SSH_FXP_READLINK, Size: 58, Number: 12051
> 2015-07-20 11:00:15.950 Type: SSH_FXP_STAT, Size: 58, Number: 12305
< 2015-07-20 11:00:16.005 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 11788
. 2015-07-20 11:00:16.005 Storing reserved response
< 2015-07-20 11:00:16.062 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 41, Number: 12051
. 2015-07-20 11:00:16.062 Link resolved to "target.txt".
< 2015-07-20 11:00:16.062 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 12305
< 2015-07-20 11:00:16.063 Status code: 1
> 2015-07-20 11:00:16.063 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 13, Number: 12548
```